# How to boost hibernate-search query with field values?

Tags: lucene, hibernate-search

I have two fields in an entity class:

1. establishmentName
2. contactType

***contactType*** has values like PBX, GSM, TEL and FAX

I want a scoring mechanism as to get the most matching data first then PBX, TEL, GSM and FAX.

Scoring:

- On **establishmentName** to get the most matching data first
- On **contactType** to get first PBX then TEL and so on

My final query is:

> (+establishmentName:kamran~1^2.5 +(contactType:PBX^2.0 contactType:TEL^1.8 contactType:GSM^1.6 contactType:FAX^1.4))

But it not returning the result.

**My question is, how to boost a specific field on different values basis ?**

We can use the following query for two different fields:

```
Query query = qb.keyword()
    .onField( field_one).boostedTo(2.0f)
    .andField( field_two)
    .matching( searchTerm)
    .createQuery();
```

But i need to boost a field on its values as in my case it is *contactType*.

**My dataset:**
(establishmentName : Concert Decoration, contactType : GSM),
(establishmentName : Elissa Concert, contactType : TEL),
(establishmentName : Yara Concert, contactType : FAX),
(establishmentName : E Concept, contactType : TEL),
(establishmentName : Infinity Concept, contactType : FAX),
(establishmentName : SD Concept, contactType : PBX),
(establishmentName : Broadcom Technical Concept, contactType : GSM),
(establishmentName : Concept Businessmen, contactType : PBX)

**By searching the term=concert(fuzzy query on establishmentName), it should return me the list as below:**
(establishmentName : Elissa Concert, contactType : TEL)

> [term=concert, exact matching so it will be on top by keeping the
>   order as PBX, TEL, GSM and FAX]

(establishmentName : Concert Decoration, contactType : GSM)

> [term=concert, exact matching and by keeping the order as PBX, TEL,
>   GSM and FAX]

(establishmentName : Yara Concert, contactType : FAX)

> [term=concert, exact matching and by keeping the order as PBX, TEL,
>   GSM and FAX]

(establishmentName : Concept Businessmen, contactType : PBX)

> [term=concert, partial matching and keeping the order as PBX, TEL, GSM
>   and FAX]

(establishmentName : SD Concept, contactType : PBX)

> [term=concert, partial matching and keeping the order as PBX, TEL, GSM
>   and FAX]

(establishmentName : E Concept, contactType : TEL)

> [term=concert, partial matching and keeping the order as PBX, TEL,
>   GSM and FAX]

(establishmentName : Broadcom Technical Concept, contactType : GSM)

> [term=concert, partial matching and keeping the order as PBX, TEL, GSM
>   and FAX]

(establishmentName : Infinity Concept, contactType : FAX)

> [term=concert, partial matching and keeping the order as PBX, TEL, GSM
>   and FAX]

Comment: Your definition of the sort should be refined. What does "most matching data" mean? Do you mean "documents with a score higher than X"? Or "documents that match first, then documents that do not match"?

It will probably be easier if  you give examples of datasets, and how you expect the sorted results to look like. Do not forget to take into account paging.

Comment: @yrodiere i want to make the results ordered by scoring based on 2 criteria: first criteria(fuzzy query on establishmentName), here "most matching data" mean
"documents same or most close to the search term in the query: second criteria(contactType has values like PBX, GSM, TEL and FAX), to get order
as first PBX then GSM and so on. here i want to set contactType values scores and then combine it with the fuzzy one.

Comment: @yrodiere i have provided the datasets in the post. Please have a look in the post. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand you basically want a two-phase sort:

1. Put exact matches before other (fuzzy) matches.
2. Sort by contact type.

The second sort is trivial, but the first one will require a bit of work.
You can actually rely on scoring to implement it.

Essentially the idea would be to run a disjunction of multiple queries, and to assign a constant score to each query.

Instead of doing this:

```java
Query query = qb.keyword()
    .fuzzy().withEditDistanceUpTo(1)
    .boostedTo(2.5f)
    .onField("establishmentName")
    .matching(searchTerm)
    .createQuery();
```

Do this:

```java
Query query = qb.bool()
    .should(qb.keyword()
        .withConstantScore().boostedTo(100.0f) // Higher score, sort first
        .onField("establishmentName")
        .matching(searchTerm)
        .createQuery())
    .should(qb.keyword()
        .fuzzy().withEditDistanceUpTo(1)
        .withConstantScore().boostedTo(1.0f) // Lower score, sort last
        .onField("establishmentName")
        .matching(searchTerm)
        .createQuery())
    .createQuery();
```

The matched documents will be the same, *but* now the query will assign predictable scores: 1.0 for fuzzy-only matches, and 101.0 (1 from the fuzzy query and 100 from the exact query) for exact matches.

This way, you can define the sort as follows:

```java
fullTextQuery.setSort(qb.sort()
    .byScore()
    .andByField("contactType")
    .createSort());
```

This may not be a very elegant, or optimized solution, but I think it will work.

To customize the relative order of contact types, I would suggest a different approach: use a [custom bridge](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/search/5.11/reference/en-US/html_single/#section-custom-bridges) to index numbers instead of the "PBX"/"TEL"/etc., assigning to each contact type the ordinal you expect. Essentially something like that:

```java
public class Establishment {

@Field(name = "contactType_sort", bridge = @FieldBridge(impl = ContactTypeOrdinalBridge.class))
private ContactType contactType;

}

public class ContactTypeOrdinalBridge implements MetadataProvidingFieldBridge {

    @Override
    public void set(String name, Object value, Document document, LuceneOptions luceneOptions) {
        if ( value != null ) {
          int ordinal = getOrdinal((ContactType) value);
          luceneOptions.addNumericFieldToDocument(name, ordinal, document);
          luceneOptions.addNumericDocValuesFieldToDocument(name, ordinal, document);
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void configureFieldMetadata(String name, FieldMetadataBuilder builder) {
        builder.field(name, FieldType.INTEGER).sortable(true);
    }

    private int getOrdinal(ContactType value) {
        switch( value ) {
          case PBX: return 0;
          case TEL: return 1;
          case GSM: return 2;
          case PBX: return 3;
          default: return 4;
        }
    }
}
```

Then reindex, and sort like this:

```java
fullTextQuery.setSort(qb.sort()
    .byScore()
    .andByField("contactType_sort")
    .createSort());
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. I am getting the following error after applied sort on contactType(note: i am using hibernate seach 5.10): **java.lang.IllegalStateException: unexpected docvalues type NONE for field 'contactType.name' (expected=NUMERIC). Use UninvertingReader or index with docvalues.**

Comment: @KamranUllah You need to mark your field as sortable. Use `@SortableField(forField = "name")`.

Comment: I am still getting the same error. let me show you my settings:
ContactType Entity: `@SortableField(forField = "name")
 @Field(store =Store.YES, bridge = @FieldBridge(impl = ContactTypeComparator.class))
 @Column(name = "NAME")
 private String name;`
Establishment Entity: `@IndexedEmbedded(prefix = "contactType.", includePaths = {"id", "name"})
 @ManyToOne
 @JoinColumn(name = "CONTACT_TYPE")
 private ContactTypeEntity contactType;`
Query: `query.setSort(queryBuilder.sort().byScore().andByField("contactType.name").createSort());`

Comment: Now when i have commented the line `query.setSort(queryBuilder.sort().byScore().andByField("contactType.name").createSort());`, it throwing  **HSEARCH000324: The fieldBridge for field 'contactType.name' is an instance of 'class ae.etisalat.dq.common.ContactTypeComparator', which does not implement TwoWayFieldBridge. Projected fields must have a TwoWayFieldBridge.**

Comment: I am using projection as: `query.setProjection("id", "establishmentNameEn", "contactType.name", ...);` I am showing **contactType.name** as PBX,TEL etc on UI instead of numbers. I have also used TwoWayFieldBridge inteface and its method as: `@Override
public Object get(String name, Document document) { 
 return document.get( name );
}` but the error still exists.

Comment: I don't know what you did, but my suggestion was to add *another* field with the suffix "_sort", using the bridge I gave. If you want projections, use two fields: one for the projection, storing the string, and one for the sort, storing the number. If you need more help, update your question with the code of your entities and the code that builds the query.

Comment: i have posted a separate question regrading the issue. Please have a look [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59752591/error-on-using-a-custom-bridge-of-hibernate-search)