# Error on using a custom bridge of hibernate-search

Tags: hibernate-search

I have two entities:

```
@Indexed
@Entity
@Table(name = "LK_CONTACT_TYPE")
public class ContactTypeEntity {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID")
    @DocumentId
    Integer id;

    @SortableField
    @Field(store = Store.YES, bridge = @FieldBridge(impl = ContactTypeComparator.class))
    @Column(name = "NAME")
    String name; 

    getter() .. setter()..
}



@Indexed
 @Entity
 @Table(name = "DIRECTORY")
 public class DirectoryEntity {
    ....
    @IndexedEmbedded(prefix = "contactType.", includePaths = {"id", "name"})
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "CONTACT_TYPE")
    private ContactTypeEntity contactType;

    getter() ... setter()...
}

public class ContactTypeComparator implements MetadataProvidingFieldBridge, TwoWayStringBridge {

     @Override
    public void set(String name, Object value, Document document, LuceneOptions luceneOptions) {
        if ( value != null ) {
          int ordinal = getOrdinal(value.toString());
          luceneOptions.addNumericFieldToDocument(name, ordinal, document);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void configureFieldMetadata(String name, FieldMetadataBuilder builder) {
        builder.field(name, FieldType.INTEGER).sortable(true);
    }

    private int getOrdinal(ContactType value) {
        switch( value ) {
          case PBX: return 0;
          case TEL: return 1;
          case GSM: return 2;
          case FAX: return 3;
          default: return 4;
        }
    }


    @Override
    public Object get(String name, Document document) {
    return document.get( name );
   }

    @Override
    public String objectToString(Object object) {
    return object.toString();
   }
}
```

and Query part:

```
...
query.setSort(queryBuilder.sort().byScore().andByField("contactType.name").createSort());
query.setProjection(... , "contactType.name",...);
...
```

I am getting the following error:
**java.lang.IllegalStateException: unexpected docvalues type NONE for field 'contactType.name' (expected=NUMERIC). Use UninvertingReader or index with docvalues.**

Note: I am using hibernate-search 5.10.
*I want to show **contactType.name** name on UI instead of number.*
[For more detail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59658935/how-to-boost-hibernate-search-query-with-field-values/59721290?noredirect=1#comment105613864_59721290)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems my original suggestion was missing a bit in the `set()` method, in order to add the docvalues:

```
     @Override
    public void set(String name, Object value, Document document, LuceneOptions luceneOptions) {
        if ( value != null ) {
          int ordinal = getOrdinal(value.toString());
          luceneOptions.addNumericFieldToDocument(name, ordinal, document);
          // ADD THIS
          luceneOptions.addNumericDocValuesFieldToDocument(name, ordinal, document);
        }
    }
```

On top of that, if you need to use the field for both sort and projection, I would recommend declaring *two* fields. Otherwise the projection will return integers, which is not what you want.

So, do this:

```
@Indexed
@Entity
@Table(name = "LK_CONTACT_TYPE")
public class ContactTypeEntity {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID")
    @DocumentId
    Integer id;

    @SortableField
    // CHANGE THESE TWO LINES
    @Field(store = Store.YES)
    @Field(name = "name_sort", bridge = @FieldBridge(impl = ContactTypeComparator.class))
    @Column(name = "NAME")
    String name; 

    getter() .. setter()..
}



@Indexed
 @Entity
 @Table(name = "DIRECTORY")
 public class DirectoryEntity {
    ....
    // CHANGE THIS LINE
    @IndexedEmbedded(prefix = "contactType.", includePaths = {"id", "name", "name_sort"})
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "CONTACT_TYPE")
    private ContactTypeEntity contactType;

    getter() ... setter()...
}

public class ContactTypeComparator implements MetadataProvidingFieldBridge, TwoWayStringBridge {

     @Override
    public void set(String name, Object value, Document document, LuceneOptions luceneOptions) {
        if ( value != null ) {
          int ordinal = getOrdinal(value.toString());
          luceneOptions.addNumericFieldToDocument(name, ordinal, document);
          // ADD THIS LINE
          luceneOptions.addNumericDocValuesFieldToDocument(name, ordinal, document);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void configureFieldMetadata(String name, FieldMetadataBuilder builder) {
        builder.field(name, FieldType.INTEGER).sortable(true);
    }

    private int getOrdinal(ContactType value) {
        switch( value ) {
          case PBX: return 0;
          case TEL: return 1;
          case GSM: return 2;
          case FAX: return 3;
          default: return 4;
        }
    }


    @Override
    public Object get(String name, Document document) {
    return document.get( name );
   }

    @Override
    public String objectToString(Object object) {
    return object.toString();
   }
}
```

Then query like this:

```
...
query.setSort(queryBuilder.sort().byScore().andByField("contactType.name_sort").createSort());
query.setProjection(... , "contactType.name",...);
...
```